# Floating of labels not working in yii2

Tags: php, css, forms, yii2

i have created a form in yii2 basic and used material design to enable floating labels but its labels are not floating above when i click the input field. Here is my code for form.

```
    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => ['index'],
                'method' => 'get',
    ]);
    ?>


    <div class="panel-body container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-group form-material floating" data-plugin="formMaterial">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'corporation_name',[  'labelOptions' => [ 'class' => 'floating-label' ]])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control'])->label('Corporation Name') ?>    
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-material floating" data-plugin="formMaterial">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'user_first_name',[  'labelOptions' => [ 'class' => 'floating-label' ]])->textinput(['class' => 'form-control'])->label('Corporation Admin'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-material floating" data-plugin="formMaterial">
                        <div class="example"> <b role="presentation"></b>
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'corporation_status')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->appstatues->status, ['prompt' => 'Status'])->label(false); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group form-material floating m-t-27" data-plugin="formMaterial">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn-primary btn waves-effect waves-light   waves-effect']) ?>
                    <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn-primary btn waves-effect waves-light   waves-effect', 'onclick' => 'location.href = "/admin/corporations";']) ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

can anybody tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Chances are nobody will create an Yii app to test your code. Besides, you don't specify which material design library you are using. But, since your issue is related to frontend, which is always `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS`, you'll greatly improve your chances of getting the question answered and problem fixed if you create a [mcve] where you would add the output `HTML` and link appropriate resources so the problem could be reproduced and inspected here, on SO. At the very least, please specify the MD library you are using. Also, is it loading properly? (for the rest of page, I mean).

Answer (score 1):

Have you look in inspect element?

If I understand you well...

Try to remove divs around input form. When you bind form for model you already have divs around input. Try this...

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ime',['options'=>['class'=>'form-group form-material floating', 'data-plugin'=> 'formMaterial'], 'labelOptions' => [ 'class' => 'floating-label' ]])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control'])->label('Corporation Name') ?>
```